# What replies can be said while waiting for person behind you to finish davening?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei

One should not take his 3 steps backward after davening *shmoneh esrei* if there is a person directly behind him still davening <sup>[citation needed]</sup>. I believe this is true no matter how far the person behind him is, but I'm certain that it's true if he's less than 4 *amot* away. Since he is not able to take his steps back to complete *shmoneh esrei*, I would imagine that he is not able to reply to all (or perhaps any) parts of davening that would normally be responded to such as *barukh hu uvarukh shemo* and *amein* to the *berakhot* of *chazarat hasha"tz*, *kedusha*, *amein yehei shemei rabba*, etc. What kinds of responses are permitted in this state?

Assume that the person has said *yihyu leratzon*... but has not yet taken three steps back and said *oseh shalom*.

Comment: http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5772/lechlecha.html "If those options are not available, he should recite Oseh Shalom without stepping back three steps and then walk away"[10]

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53594.

Comment: @joshwaxman that was talking about the case where there is a pressing need to leave.

Comment: You can also take 3 steps to the side.

Comment: @CashCow Not if doing that also passes in front of someone still davening.